# Use style-identification tag in conjunction with particular medium tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I've recently added the [style-identification](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/style-identification) tag, and have been editing them into questions retroactively.
I keep removing the medium tags (e.g. [drawing](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drawing), [sewing](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sewing), [painting](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/painting)) in the process, since most questions are not about the *use* of those mediums (for some examples see [here](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/style-identification)).

But now I wonder if keeping those tags wouldn't be the better way to go: while these questions are not about the *use* of those mediums, it will allow users to more easily find those posts, to serve as inspiration for tackling a problem or simply for experimenting.

**Should** [style-identification](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/style-identification) **be used in combination with [*medium*]?**

Comment: For now, I will try to keep the original tags, in as far as they have been added to questions correctly, or add a new one pertaining to the medium in question (added as comment, to allow it to be upvoted separately from the main question).